# onClick Notification to fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on notification part. I am able to navigate user to activity onclick of Notification message. My actual task is to navigate user to fragment.

Here is the notification code which works fine.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Lugmah Order Status")
                    .setContentText("The Order Status of Order Id: "+selectedOrderId+ " is: "+status_desc)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;

    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    targetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    targetIntent.putExtra("isTrackOrder", false);
    targetIntent.putExtra("orderNotification", "orderNotification");
    targetIntent.putExtra("isLoggedIn", true);
    targetIntent.putExtra("status_desc", status_desc);
    targetIntent.putExtra("selectedOrderId", selectedOrderId);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

I have added **MainActivity.java** in intent because that is the place I load all fragments. In this activity, I did something like this.

Here is the code inside onCreate():

```
String orderNotification = getIntent().getStringExtra("orderNotification");

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (orderNotification != null)
        {
            if (orderNotification.equals("orderNotification"))
            {
                TrackOrderFragment trackOrderFragment = new TrackOrderFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, trackOrderFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(orderNotification))` instead of  if `(orderNotification != null)`

Comment: You also need to override `onNewIntent`

Comment: @Michal_196 onNewIntent.. where should i put it?

Comment: Put in your activity class. Its a override method. Move your all code in it instead of _onCreate()_ method

Comment: @Piyush Let me try this

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your notification code works fine you need to adjust a bit the code onCreate.

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
   String orderNotification = getIntent().getStringExtra("orderNotification");  

  if (orderNotification.equals("orderNotification"))
            {
                TrackOrderFragment trackOrderFragment = new TrackOrderFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, trackOrderFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
```

You need to check if you are receiving any extras every time your activity runs onCreate because a null pointer exception can occur.

Comment: If you find it helpful can you mark the answer as the correct one. Thanks.